# primefaces tabView activeIndex issue

Tags: jsf, indexing, primefaces, tabview

I have Primefaces TabView with two Tab like:

```
<p:tabView dynamic="true" cache="false"
           onTabShow="scrollBottom(#{stanzaBean.activeIndex})"
           tabChangeListener="#{messaggioBean.onTabChange}"
           activeIndex="#{stanzaBean.activeIndex}" >
```

it works fine, except that when I change the Tab the activeIndex isn't updated on the Server and it returns always the default value.
I'm using primefaces 2.2.1.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you do in the tabChangeListener?

Comment: in the tabChangeListener I want to update some data. And i need the activeIndex to retrive the correct data.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Going by the [PrimeFaces ShowCase example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/tabviewChangeListener.jsf), if you give each tab an id:

```
<p:tabView tabChangeListener="#{indexBean.onTabChange}" >
    <p:tab title="tab 0" id="tab0"></p:tab>
    <p:tab title="tab 1" id="tab1" ></p:tab>
    <p:tab title="tab 2" id="tab2"></p:tab>               
</p:tabView>
```

you can get that tab id in the tabChangeListener.

```
public void onTabChange(TabChangeEvent event) {       
    System.out.println("tab id = " + event.getTab().getId());
}
```

Then you'll know which tab was selected.

---

Edit:

There is an open PrimeFaces [issue 1640 TabView: Wrong activeIndex in TabChangeListener, always 0](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=1640&q=activeIndex&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Module%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20TargetVersion%20Reporter%20Owner%20Summary) on the problem you are having.

---

Edit 2:

With PrimeFaces 5.0 and up the `tabChangeListener` is no longer available on the `tabView` element but should be used via an explicit ajax tag with a tabChange event.

```
 <p:tabView id="analysisSections" value="#{analysisBean.analysis.sections}" var="section" activeIndex="#{analysisBean.activeIndex}">
      <p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{analysisBean.onTabChange}"/>
```

Also you can directly get index of tab:

```
public void onTabChange(TabChangeEvent event) {
    activeIndex = ((TabView) event.getSource()).getIndex();
}
```

with all these changes, activeIndex works properly.

Comment: it seems this variable is for initial setting of active tab, not meant to be updated.

Comment: I got index `-1`using `((TabView) event.getSource()).getIndex()`.

Answer (score 8):

this worked for me:

```
public void onTabChange(TabChangeEvent event) {
        Tab activeTab = event.getTab();
        tabPanelIndex = ((TabView)event.getSource()).getChildren().indexOf(activeTab);
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Although the question was related to PrimeFaces 2.2.1, I like to mention that in modern PrimeFaces versions (tested with version 6.2) there is no need to trigger a separate event when attribute `dynamic` is set to `true` and `cache` is set to `false`. By using this attribute combination the active index is automatically updated on the server when another tab is selected.

**Facelet:**

```
<p:tabView activeIndex="#{stanzaBean.activeIndex}"
           cache="false"
           dynamic="true">
```

**Bean:**

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class StanzaBean implements Serializable {

    private int activeIndex;

    public int getActiveIndex() {
        return activeIndex;
    }

    /**
     * Automatically called whenever a tab changes and dynamic="true"
     * and cache="false".
     */
    public void setActiveIndex(int activeIndex) {
        this.activeIndex = activeIndex;

        // do other stuff when tab changes
    }

}
```